# MongoDB connection reset by peer

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo, geojson, iteration

I've looked at other solutions to this, such as:

- [Mongodb: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961648/mongodb-connection-reset-by-peer)
- [Mongodb : AutoReconnect, Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479907/mongodb-autoreconnect-connection-reset-by-peer)

But still have this error.  I'm trying to load a large GeoJSON file into MongoDB.

Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/mittenchops/6499844

using the iterative json parser here: https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload2mongo.py", line 57, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "upload2mongo.py", line 52, in main
    loader(renamesh2json(argv[1]), argv[2])
  File "upload2mongo.py", line 22, in loader
    db[collection].insert(d)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 359, in insert
    continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 853, in _send_message
    raise AutoReconnect(str(e))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Why am I receiving this strange error about my connection shutting down?

Comment: Look into a mongod log file (or mongos log if you are using shard cluster). That may give you much better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: Are crossing a firewall/proxy on the way to your MongoDB instance?

Comment: Nope, not crossing a firewall or proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is an answer or even makes sense, but I added one more loop in my insert sequence, and that corrected the problem.  It seems that the original object I thought I was inserting was actually a list of documents instead of document-level, and this was implicitly batch-inserted---when I thought I was actually inserting one document at a time, I thought I was already looping at the document level.

It appears that over the course of the batch insert, the connection closed.